# C++ Creating Binary Search Tree: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Bad Algorithm or coding error?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, exc-bad-access

## Question: I keep receiving exc_bad_access (process code 11) error. Is this due to a bad algorithm or simply a coding error? Can anyone help me fix it?

My class assignment is to create a binary search tree whose nodes can store a name, a balance, and a key. Nodes are to be organized and searched for using the key. This tree should support insertion, inorder traversal, and searching based on a key (I haven't built this function yet). I've also included several other functions to facilitate building these. If it matters, I'm using CLion on OSX High Sierra. Additionally, I get the error on the first prompt to enter node information, the error does not seem to be related to the input itself.

```
//Genghis Khan
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class node
{
public:
    int key;
    string name;
    double balance;
    node *leftptr;
    node *rightptr;
    friend class tree;
};
class tree
{
public:
    node *root, *temp, *v;

    //Constructor
    tree()
    {
        root = NULL;
        temp = root;
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        return(root == NULL);
    }


    bool isleaf(node *x)
    {
        return((x->leftptr == NULL) && (x->rightptr == NULL));
    }  

    void inorder(node *temp)
    {
        if(~isleaf(temp)) 
        {
            inorder(temp->leftptr);
            cout << "Name: " << temp->name << " " << "Balance: " << 
    temp->balance << " " << "Key: " << temp->key;
            inorder(temp->rightptr);
        }
    }

    node* createnode()
    {
        v = new node;
        cout << "Enter name (string): " << endl;
        getline(cin, v->name); 
        cout << "Enter key (integer): " << endl;
        cin >> v->key;
        cout << "Enter balance (double): " << endl;
        cin >> v->balance;
        return(v);
    }

    void set()
    {
        temp = root;
    }

    void insert(node *v)
    {
        while(~isleaf(temp)) 
        {
            if((v->key < temp->key))
            {
                temp = temp->leftptr;
                insert(v);
            }
            else if(v->key > temp->key)
            {
                temp = temp->rightptr;
                insert(v);
            }
        }
    temp->key = v->key;
    temp->balance = v->balance;
    temp->name = v->name;
    }

};

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter number of people: ";
    cin >> n;

    //Creating instance of tree, inserting all data into tree
    tree b;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b.set();
        node *a = b.createnode();
        b.insert(a);
    }

    //inorder part
    b.set();
    b.inorder(b.temp);

}
```

## The functions are (pseudocode):

```
1. function isleaf(x): return(x's left pointer and x's right pointer are both NULL)

2. function set(): set temp to root //temp will be reset every time an insertion, traversal, or search occurs

3. function createnode(): 

   v is  a new node

   get all the fields for v 

   return v

4. function insert(v)

   while(not isleaf(temp)):  
   -if(v's key < temp's key)
  temp = temp's left pointer (to the lower value child node)    
  insert(node *v)

   -if(v's key > temp's key)  
  temp = temp's right pointer (to the higher value child node)   
  insert(node *v)  
  end while  
  duplicate v's data to temp, now that temp is a leaf

5. function inorder(temp):  
   if(not isleaf(temp):  
   inorder(temp's left pointer)  
   output all info in temp node  
   inorder(temp's right pointer)
```

## Main Algorithm

for the number of nodes to be entered:
 1. set
 2. node *a = createnode
 3. insert(a)

## Update

The error seems to be coming from the 'if((v->key < temp->key))' line.

Comment: have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? Could it be failing at "b.set()"?

Comment: `if(~isleaf(temp))` looks odd. Why would you bit flip a boolean? Perhaps `if(!isleaf(temp))` is what you want here. g++ with -pedantic -Wall -Wextra flags this with a warning. The default toolchain for xcode, clang, will probably warn you as well.

Comment: @user4581301 I didn't realize that was the proper syntax. Thank you!

Comment: Recommend editing your question to add a set of input that triggers this error.

Comment: Unrelated: You have a potential bug here: `getline(cin, v->name);` the user will very likely press enter at `cin >> n;` to input the value for `n` and get the next prompt. `cin >> n;` will read and convert the number (if it's convertible. You didn't check. Oops.) and leave the end of line from hitting enter for the `getline(cin, v->name);` to pick up. `getline` instantly finds the end of line and gives an empty string. The name will then be read for `key` and break the stream. Placing a `cin.ignore` after the `cin >> n;` is needed.

Comment: Check that `v` and `temp` are pointing to valid memory.

Comment: You have a member variable `v` that looks like it is shadowed by some local variable `v`s. I don't think you need it as a member variable. Also seriously rethink the whole `temp` thing. That's what's killing your program. It's almost certainly NULL the first time you insert because you don't have a `root` yet.

Answer (score 0):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS just means that you are trying to access an invalid memory. By a quick brief,  your function isleaf doesn't check whether x is null.

May have other errors, you can debug and find it by yourself.

Comment: Answers should make some attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: @iamnoten I previously tried your suggestion to check whether x is null and only then to check its left and right pointers, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @arnavlohe15 in your insert function, first check whether the tree is empty, if is empty, just assign the node to root. If not empty, then go over your while loop.